# Json data calculation and to html

Tags: javascript, html, json, math, price

I'm new to Javascript. In fact it has a very simple answer but I can't :(

Price display javascript code;

```
 $('#totalPricefark').html(data.totalPrice);
```

Html

```
<strong id="totalPricefark">0</strong>
```

What I want to do;

data.totalPrice * 0.6 calculation  and show in #totalPricefark

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not solved with javascript :( A new Json object variable was created with php. It was solved this way. Thanks to my friends who try to help.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the value from the priceFark div, parses it into an integer via pareseInt function, and multiplies by 0.6 and populates the data into the other element.

The solution uses jQuery as your original question was using it as well.

Try this:

```js
var priceFark = parseFloat($("#totalPricefark").text());

$('#totalPricefark2').html(priceFark * 0.6);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong id="totalPricefark">2</strong>
<br/>
<strong id="totalPricefark2">1</strong>
```

Comment: Instead of "parseInt" better to use "parseFloat" as the values are double.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do something like this

```
const data = {
  totalPrice: 10
};

$('#totalPricefark').text(data.totalPrice * 0.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 var data={};
 data.totalPrice=15;
 var result=(parseFloat( data.totalPrice) * 0.6);
 $('#totalPricefark').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong id="totalPricefark">0</strong>
```